# Mac OSX Server : 502 Proxy Error : The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server

Tags: php, amazon-s3, proxy, osx-server

I have a Mac OS X Server with a PHP script that send images on a Amazon S3 (using the Amazon PHP SDK).

Sometimes, the images can be heavy, and the upload on Amazon S3 takes time, and after approximately 60 secondes, I have this error :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>502 Proxy Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Proxy Error</h1>
        <p>The proxy server received an invalid
response from an upstream server.
            <br />
The proxy server could not handle the request 
            <em>
                <a href="/insert.php">POST&nbsp;/insert.php</a>
            </em>.
            <p>
Reason: 
                <strong>Error reading from remote server</strong>
            </p>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am on Mac OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitan), and my Server tools are on version 5.1.5.

Do you have a solution to fix this error please ?

Comment: might be an idea to share your code...

Comment: My code is very simple, just do a file upload with S3 client of the Amazon PHP SDK :

            // Upload the file to Amazon S3
            $result = $this->s3Client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket' => $this->config['bucket'],
                'Key'    => $key,
                'Body'   => $fileContent,
                'ACL'    => $publicRead ? 'public-read' : 'private'
            ));

It's not a problem at the code level, because the same code works on a previous version of Mac OS X Server.

Comment: The code is irrelevant. I get the same error on just a .jpg image (with the standard <img src="bla.jpg"> tag) or even a plain html page with just a single word in its <body>Test</body>.
Its a server side issue. I just don't know how to solve it...